# Appended (-) minus Symbol in PK column of oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence, biztalk

I have a Biztalk application which is receiving xml file and doing simple insertion of the data into one oracle table using WCF-CUSTOM Adapter. My problem is sometimes it is inserting negative numbers in primary key column. For primary key insertion I am using sequence.

I have double checked the sequence manually also, it is not generating negative number as `NEXTVAL`.

Below is my Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "TEST"."SEQ_TESTBNUMBER_TMP"  
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 187 
NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

It means the value which I am getting in my primary key column is like that

```
197
-196
195
194
193
192
191
190
189
188
-187
-185
-186
-184
183
182
181
-169
-168
167
166
165
164
```

That is displaying as negative value but in actuality it is not. It is inserting in sequence but in some cases only it is appending (-) minus symbol before it.  I don't know why.

**Trigger code**:

```
TRIGGER "TEST"."TR_TESTBNUMBER_TMP" 
    before INSERT ON "TEST"."NUMBER_RL" 
    FOR EACH row 
BEGIN 
    IF inserting THEN 
        IF :NEW."PKID" IS NULL THEN
            SELECT SEQ_TESTBNUMBER_TMP.nextval 
            INTO :NEW."PKID" 
            FROM dual;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Is there a **trigger** involved? Post the trigger code.

Comment: `That is displaying as negative value but in actual it is not.` What? Checkout `select * from table where pk = -168` to make sure that's not a display issue. Someone inserts/updates those negative values.

Comment: Yes Lalit Trigger is involved, Below is Trigger Code TRIGGER "TEST"."TR_TESTBNUMBER_TMP" 
   before insert on "TEST"."NUMBER_RL" 
   for each row 
begin  
   if inserting then 
      if :NEW."PKID" is null then 
         select SEQ_TESTBNUMBER_TMP.nextval into :NEW."PKID" from dual; 
      end if; 
   end if; 
end;

Comment: **Don't add code to comments, add it to your question.** For now I have done that for you. Anyway, the reason for negative values seems pretty straight to me. See the answer.

Comment: If a value is supplied manually in an insert statement, this will be stored in the table: `insert into number_rl (pkid) values (-1);` your trigger will not prevent that. Btw: you don't need the `select` to obtain the sequence value: `:new.pkid := SEQ_TESTBNUMBER_TMP.nextval;` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IF :NEW."PKID" IS NULL THEN

The above condition is not enough to handle the correct insertion of sequence value. Your application is inserting **negative values** for `PKID` and not **null values**. So, the below condition will fail:

```
IF :NEW."PKID" IS NULL THEN
```

Whenever there is a negative value for `PKID`, the above condition fails and inserts the negative value directly into the table. You need to handle the negative values also in the **IF** condition.

Modify it to:

```
IF :NEW."PKID" IS NULL OR :NEW."PKID" < 0 THEN
```

Comment: Yes Lalit I understood your point. But As you can see the code of my sequence, it should not generate negative value. In some cases only it is generating.

Comment: @AnshuKumar "*it should not generate negative value. In some cases only it is generating*" Why not? That is what I explained to you. Your application is inserting negative values, but your trigger is only able to handle NULL values. **Whenever there is a negative value being inserted, the sequence is not at all being used, as your IF condition in trigger doesn't check negative values. Therefore the negative value is directly inserted.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "Your application is inserting negative values" Can you tell me where is the source for these -ve values? When I ran the query in the Sequence, the counter is increasing properly with positive values. And you can see the counter increment sequentially with few -ve values in between.

Comment: "*Can you tell me where is the source for these -ve values?*" How could I tell your source? Only you would know it. Isn't it? it is your system, you are working on it. The source is the application which uses this table. Did you even try to put the fix and verify?

Comment: I have 5 columns in my table. For the first column(where we are getting -ve value sometimes) that is PK, I am using above mentioned sequence to insert value and and for rest 4 columns we are inserting value from xml file using BizTalk and in that xml file we have only value for those four columns only, so we are getting always null value for first column. So there is no point of getting negative value from application.

Comment: @AnshuKumar There is no way Oracle would insert negative values automatically. Either someone manually inserted it, for which your trigger got fired, however, it couldn't stop it as you don't check that condition at all. So, you can only fix it by applying the IF condition I provided. **If you want to confirm, just manually insert and see yourself. if it is a production environment, then create a small test case in your test environment and see yourself.**

Comment: @AnshuKumar Please mark it as answered, would help others too! Let me know if you want help with testing.